# How Do I Properly Make a Meteor Template Reactive?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

My app displays a collection of items and I'd like to add an item drilldown view.

I've only been able to get half of the solution working; I find the appropriate document and use that document to render the template:

```
var item = Items.findOne('my_id');

$('#main').html(
    Meteor.render(function () {
        return Templates.item(item)
    }));
```

This renders the individual item successfully and the appropriate events are bound.

Here's the rub, *the template isn't reactive*! If I change its data using the associated event handlers or from the console, the template isn't updated. However, a page refresh will reveal the updated data.

I'm a Meteor noobie, so it's probably something very simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you have an exceeding closing parenthesis? `return Templates.item(item))` should be `return Templates.item(item)`

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo. Updating the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you aren't using the templates in they way they were really intended to be.

A meteor app starts with the main html markup which can only exist once in your app..

```
<head>
  <title>My New Fancy App</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{>templateName}}
</body>
```

Then you add a template..

```
<template name="templateName">
  {{#each items}}
    template or relevant html goes here..
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Now you need a template helper to give you data for your {{#each items}} block helper..

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  items: function(){ return Items.find({}) }
});
```

All this gets defined on the client side..

Then you'll need a collection and the collection should be defined on both the client and server.

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection('items');
```

This should now work as long as you have records in your collection.

Since you wish to only wish to render a single document you can change the helper and template just slightly..

first the helper becomes:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  item: function(){ return Items.findOne() }
});
```

Then the template can reference the values of the returned document through document, so we change our template to:

```
<template name="templateName">
  {{item.propertyName}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm looking to render a single member of the items collection. Is this not aligned with the Meteor conventions?

Comment: There you go, I've updated my answer to show how to just render a single document from a collection into a template. Hope this helps.